# Google BigQuery SQL Statement

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, github-archive

I am trying to get some data from the GitHub Archive using Google Big Query. The current amount of data I am requesting is too much for BigQuery to process (at least in the free tier) so I am trying to limit the scope of my request.

I want to limit the data such that only repositories that **currently** have more than 1000 stars will return historical data. Its more complicated than just saying repository_watchers > 1000 because that will exclude the historical data for the first 1000 stars a repository got.

```
SELECT repository_name, repository_owner, created_at, type, repository_url, repository_watchers
FROM [githubarchive:github.timeline]
WHERE type="WatchEvent"
ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

EDIT: Solution I used (based on answer by @Brian)

```
select y.repository_name, y.repository_owner, y.created_at, y.type, y.repository_url, y.repository_watchers
  from [githubarchive:github.timeline] y
  join (select repository_url, max(repository_watchers)
          from [githubarchive:github.timeline] x
         where x.type = 'WatchEvent'
         group by repository_url
        having max(repository_watchers) > 1000) x
    on y.repository_url = x.repository_url
  where y.type = 'WatchEvent'
 order by y.repository_name, y.repository_owner, y.created_at desc
```

Comment: repository_watchers column changes over time and reflects the number of stars at the given created_date?

Comment: Yes thats exactly right. The repository_watchers shows the number of watchers at the time of created_at

Comment: Note that costs in BigQuery reflect the size of the columns involved in the query. So filtering out half of the information still goes through all of it. To reduce costs, do this exact same filtering, but export the results to a new table - then run your queries over this new table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
select y.*
  from [githubarchive :github.timeline] y
  join (select repository_name, max(repository_watchers)
          from [githubarchive :github.timeline]
         where x.type = 'WatchEvent'
         group by repository_name
        having max(repository_watchers) > 1000) x
    on y.repository_name = x.repository_name
 order by y.created_at desc
```

If that syntax is not supported you can use a 3 step solution like this:

**Step 1: Find which REPOSITORY_NAME values have at least one record w/ a REPOSITORY_WATCHERS amount > 1000**

```
select repository_name, max(repository_watchers) as curr_watchers
  from [githubarchive :github.timeline]
 where type = 'WatchEvent'
 group by repository_name
having max(repository_watchers) > 1000
```

**Step 2: Store that result as a table, call it SUB**

**Step 3: Run the following against SUB (and your original table)**

```
select y.*
  from [githubarchive :github.timeline] y
  join sub x
    on y.repository_name = x.repository_name
 order by y.created_at desc
```

Comment: Thanks for the information. I don't think it will work with Google Big Query because it only allows one query at a time: 
Query Failed
Error: error at: 3.16 - 8.11. Only one query can be executed at a time.
Do you know how this could be split up?

Comment: @AnkushAgrawal ah, I didn't notice that, never even heard of 'Google Big Query'. I don't really think you can do this without a subquery or an inline view (a subquery in the from clause)

Comment: Do you know of a way this can be split up into two queries? I am able to save the data from a query into a table and I can query a second table.

Comment: @AnkushAgrawal I'll edit w/ a way you can run 2 queries to do it but try the query in my edit to see if that syntax is supported

Comment: @AnkushAgrawal no problem, will be interested to see what worked

Comment: The first query worked without problem for me in BigQuery. Thanks for your answer Brian! (Btw, try BigQuery for free, you might fall in love with it)